# Unable to push build to heroku due to react/jsx-runtime

Tags: reactjs, npm, heroku, heroku-cli

I am getting this error

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' in '/tmp/build_42beb485/node_modules/@strapi/icons/dist'
remote: Did you mean 'jsx-runtime.js'?
```

when i try to upload a strapi application to heroku using this command  `git push heroku-staging staging:master`

My package json file

```
{
  "name": "appNAME",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@_sh/strapi-plugin-ckeditor": "^1.0.7",
    "@strapi/plugin-graphql": "^4.1.8",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.4.3",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.4.3",
    "@strapi/provider-email-sendgrid": "^4.1.12",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3": "^4.1.9",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.4.3",
    "chargebee": "^2.10.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.11",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "pg-connection-string": "^2.5.0",
    "sanitize-filename": "^1.6.3",
    "strapi-provider-email-smtp": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "XXXXXX-bad0-4fee-XXXX-XXXXXX"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.19.1 <=18.x.x",
    "npm": "8.11.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: are you using typescript ?

Comment: this is a strapi project

Comment: It is not a solution if you are actually using GraphQL, but in my case I removed `@strapi/plugin-graphql` dependency since it was causing incompatibility with `@strapi/icons` and I am using REST api in my client app. So `yarn remove @strapi/plugin-graphql` did the trick for me.